# Using FirePHP4Chrome with CakePHP 2.6

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp, firephp, cakephp-2.6

I'm installed the debug_kit, and dropped the FirePHP core into the applications /Vendors folder, and added:

```
function fclog($data, $logLevel = 'log', $label = null) {
    if (Configure::read() > 0) {
        App::uses('FireCake', 'DebugKit.Lib');
        FireCake::$logLevel($data, $label);
    }
}
```

to /Config/bootstrap.php and tried invoking using:

```
fclog('hello world', 'error', 'Oh no we have a lot of data!');
```

in my controller with the FirePHP4Chrome plugin enabled based on this [post](http://zenofcoding.com/2013/08/23/easy-cakephp-logging-to-firebug-with-debugkit-and-firephp/).

Does this work in Chrome using the FirePHP4Chrome plugin?  I tried it also in FireFox and I don't see anything in the console either.